# Trying to write shared protobuf definitions

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create shared protobuf definitions in a shared go module, but I'm not having much luck.  Specifically:
- I want a proto file in module protos that contains shared definitions.
- Other proto files in module protos would reference the shared definitions.
- Module protos-use would reference module protos (via go.mod)
- Module protos-use go code would import and use definitions from module protos
- Both modules are stored in github.com

I'm unable to get the various package names to align.  No matter what I use, *something* fails.  Currently, module protos doesn't have any errors, but go mod tidy on module protos-use fails.

Module protos is at https://github.com/rob-woerner/protos
Module protos-use is at https://github.com/rob-woerner/protos-use

I haven't found an example that addresses this scenario.  If I simply duplicate the shared proto definitions everywhere, I can get it to work.  The most recent error is:
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/rob-woerner/protos/messages
go: finding module for package github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common
github.com/rob-woerner/protos-use/code imports
github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common: module github.com/rob-woerner/protos@latest found (XXX), but does not contain package github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common
github.com/rob-woerner/protos-use/code imports
github.com/rob-woerner/protos/messages: module github.com/rob-woerner/protos@latest found (XXX), but does not contain package github.com/rob-woerner/protos/messages

But I emphasize that I get lots of different errors, depending on what package names I use in the dozen or so places that need package names.

If anyone knows of a working example, or if this is not supported, I'd appreciate it.

Code snippets are elided for compactness

---

Module protos:

go.mod
Makefile
protobuf:
   common.proto
   messages.proto
pb:
   common.pb.go
   messages.pb.go

---

Module protos-use:
go.mod
code:
   project.go

---

Module protos:
go.mod:
module protos
go 1.16
require google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1

---

protobuf/common.proto:
package common;
option go_package = "github.com/rob-woerner/protos";
enum MyState { LOGGED_OUT = 0; }

---

protobuf/messages.proto:
import "common.proto";
package messages;
option go_package = "github.com/rob-woerner/protos";
message MyRequest { common.MyState state = 1; }

---

Makefile:
protos:
   protoc --proto_path=protobuf --go_out=plugins=grpc:pb --go_opt=module=github.com/rob-woerner/protos protobuf/*.proto

---

Module protos-use:

go.mod:
module github.com/rob-woerner/protos-use
go 1.16
require (
   github.com/rob-woerner/protos latest
)

---

code/project.go:
package code
import (
   "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common"
   "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/messages"
)
func MyFunc() messages.MyMessage {
   return messages.MyMessage { state: common.MyState_LOGGED_OUT}
}

Answer (score 2):

This is challenging with protobufs and is poorly documented.

Part of the complexity -- I sense -- is that the protobuf maintainers are trying to solve for the myriad runtimes and packages that may be used.

If I understand your problem correctly, with what you have, `protos-use` is struggling because `code/product.go` should:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/pb/common" // /pb/
    ...
)
```

I've got a working mechanism that I'll try to apply to your mechanism. I think the references to `common` aren't your issue but the overall structure and modules vs. packages imports:

- `github.com/foo/protos`
- `github.com/bar/app`

In `foo/protos`, I have `*.proto` files in the root (but this is just a convention and need not be the case):

- `example.proto`

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package baz;

option go_package = "github.com/foo/protos;baz";

service Some {...}
```

> **NOTE** The `;baz` this describe the eventual Go package name (`baz`) of the generated code. It need not match the the repo name (`protos`) and I don't want this because (see below), I'm putting the generated code in a non-root directory (`/some/baz`)

Then:

```sh
MODULE="github.com/foo/protos"
protoc \
--include_imports \
--include_source_info \
--proto_path=. \
--descriptor_set_out=foo.pb \
--go_out=./some/baz \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
--go-grpc_out=./some/baz \
--go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE} \
./*.proto
```

> **NOTE** This will give us a package name of `github.com/foo/protos/some/baz`

This will yield:

```sh
.
├── example.proto
├── some
│   └── baz
│       ├── example_grpc.pb.go
│       └── example.pb.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── protoc-3.17.3-linux-x86_64
```

Then, from `bar/app`, I have:

`go.mod`:

```
module github.com/bar/app

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/foo/protos v0.0.1
    ...
)
```

And, within that module, I alias the imports:

```
package main

import (
    ...
    pb "github.com/foo/protos/some/baz"
)

func main() {
    ...
    pb.RegisterSomeServer(grpcServer, ...)
```

##### Update

> **NOTE** Responding to the comment thread

`common` and `messages` are either in one package or in two.

Let's do two:

`common.proto`:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package common;

option go_package = "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common;common";

enum MyState { LOGGED_OUT = 0; }
```

`messages.proto`:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package messages;

import "common.proto";

option go_package = "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/messages;messages";

message MyRequest { common.MyState state = 1; }
```

> **NOTE** Because we want 2 packages, we need to give the protos (!) unique `package`, `go_package` names `./protos/common;common`. Although we could have `./protos/common;freddie`, the issue is that the path must be unique to give a unique package.

Then:

```sh
MODULE="github.com/rob-woerner/protos"

protoc \
--proto_path=. \
--go_out=./some \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
--go-grpc_out=./some \
--go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE}
```

> **NOTE** The use of `some` here is solely to ensure that the generated code ends up aggregated by some package (`some`) below the repo(==module) root. You can remove `/some` if you want the packages directly beneath the module root.

yields:

```sh
some
├── common
│   └── common.pb.go
└── messages
    └── messages.pb.go
```

> **NOTE** `some` becomes the root package `github.com/rob-woerner/protos/some` and `common.pb.go` is in the sub-package `github.com/rob-woerner/protos/some/common`

So, we can now:

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/some/common"
    "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/some/messages"
)

func main() {
    rqst := messages.MyRequest{
        state: common.MyState_LOGGED_OUT,
    }
    // do something with `rqst`
}
```

If you want `common` and `messages` to be in the same package, then you can just:

```proto
package protos;

option go_package = "github.com/rob-woerner/protos;protos`;
```

And:

```proto
message MyRequest { MyState state = 1; } // Now in same package
```

And then:

```sh
MODULE="github.com/rob-woerner/protos"

protoc \
--proto_path=. \
--go_out=./protos \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
--go-grpc_out=./protos \
--go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE}
```

> **NOTE** In this case, we need `_out=./protos` so that the generated files get put under the correct package (`protos`

`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    pb "github.com/rob-woerner/protos"
)

func main() {
    rqst := pb.MyRequest{
        state: pb.MyState_LOGGED_OUT,
    }
    // do something with `rqst`
}
```

Phew! I said it is challenging ;-)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I incorporated the changes you suggested. Unfortunately, the lines above in example.com don't compile:

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I added the changes you suggested. Unfortunately, my line corresponding to the lines in example.com above don't compile:<br/>

package common;

option go_package = "github.com/foo/protos;common";

yields:

protoc --include_imports --include_source_info --proto_path=protobuf --descriptor_set_out=foo.pb --go_out=./pb --go_opt=module="github.com/rob-woerner/protos" --go-grpc_out=./pb --go-grpc_opt=module="github.com/rob-woerner/protos" protobuf/*.proto
protoc-gen-go: Go package "github.com/rob-woerner/protos" has inconsistent names common (common.proto) ...

Comment: Let me see whether I can repro your config in the next 30 minutes

Comment: When I make the suggested changes to common.proto, messages.proto, and Makefile, then go mod tidy fails with:


$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common
github.com/rob-woerner/protos/some/messages imports
        github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common: no matching versions for query "latest"


Note that is still in protos.  It's trying to download itself!

Comment: If I replace "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/common" with "github.com/rob-woerner/protos/some/common" in messages.pb.go, then protos builds cleanly.  Unfortunately, then go mod tidy in protos-use gives protos@latest does not contain package githubcom/rob-woerner/protos/common

Comment: This shouldn't be that hard. Every language I've worked with allows you to share entity definitions across modules and packages without much fuss.

Comment: Yay! I solved it!  The key is to move the *.proto files to the root directory.  After adjusting the other files for that change, both protos and protos-use tidy and build without errors.  Putting the proto files in the root directory shouldn't be necessary, but I'll take it.  Many thanks to DazWilkin for your invaluable suggestions.

Comment: For anyone who cares, the working example is in the two repos mentioned above.